# Function returning issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have searched for this but couldn't find what I was looking for, does anyone know more info about this?

```
async function getToken(auth) {
  if(!(auth.startsWith('!t!'))){auth = "!t!" + auth;}
  db.get(auth).then(value => {
    if(value=="valid"){
      console.log('Token Accepted');
      return true;
    }else if(auth.slice(3) == process.env['token']){
      console.log('Master Token Accepted');
      return true;
    }else{
      console.log('Token Denied');
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

I want this to return either false or true, but when this function is called, it just returns

```
undefined
```

How should I fix this

Comment: The 'return' is returning the inner function. You want to use async without await? Just use await.

Comment: something like: const value = await db.get(auth);